# hibernate + grails error and question

Tags: hibernate, grails, mapping

I just changed all of the classes in my grails project to a new package. This involved adding the package syntax, and creating the folder structure accordingly. Now I am getting the following hibernate.MappingException:

```
2010-09-23 15:31:16,755 [main] ERROR [localhost].[/SkillsDB]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.gr
ails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.s
pringframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while
setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFacto
ry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: skillsdb.Client, at table: project, for
 columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(client)]
```

Is this something to do with my package changing? How do I resolve this? I literally changed nothing in the project except the package of my domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not determine type for: skillsdb.Client
```

cannot seem to find this object, you will need to provide more information for a more specific response